# Import errors after updating Next project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, typescript, next.js

So I recently update a Next project from Next 12 to 14, and am running into a ton of import errors when trying to run the project locally. There are too many for me to copy and paste them all, so here are some examples:

```
Import trace for requested module:
./components/Header/Header.tsx

./components/Header/Header.tsx
Attempted import error: 'react' does not contain a default export (imported as 'React').

Import trace for requested module:
./components/Header/Header.tsx

./components/Header/Header.tsx
Attempted import error: 'react' does not contain a default export (imported as 'React').

Import trace for requested module:
./components/Header/Header.tsx

./components/Logo/Logo.tsx
Attempted import error: 'react' does not contain a default export (imported as 'React').

Import trace for requested module:
./components/Logo/Logo.tsx
./components/Nav/Nav.tsx

./components/Nav/Nav.tsx
Attempted import error: 'useState' is not exported from 'react' (imported as 'useState').

Import trace for requested module:
./components/Nav/Nav.tsx

./components/Nav/Nav.tsx
Attempted import error: 'useEffect' is not exported from 'react' (imported as 'useEffect').

./node_modules/react-transition-group/esm/utils/ChildMapping.js
Attempted import error: 'cloneElement' is not exported from 'react' (imported as 'cloneElement').

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/react-transition-group/esm/utils/ChildMapping.js
./node_modules/react-transition-group/esm/TransitionGroup.js
./node_modules/react-transition-group/esm/index.js
./node_modules/@mui/material/ButtonBase/TouchRipple.js
./node_modules/@mui/material/ButtonBase/ButtonBase.js
./node_modules/@mui/material/ButtonBase/index.js
./node_modules/@mui/material/Button/Button.js
./node_modules/@mui/material/Button/index.js
./components/Header/Header.tsx

./node_modules/react-transition-group/esm/utils/ChildMapping.js
Attempted import error: 'isValidElement' is not exported from 'react' (imported as 'isValidElement').
```

I tried deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and reinstalling and haven't found the solution.

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "types": [
      "jest",
      "node"
    ],
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    },
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "esnext"
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

My next.config.cjs:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

And my package.json, if that helps:

```
{
  "name": "benedict-construction",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "test": "jest --watchAll=false",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.6",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.6",
    "@types/node": "20.5.4",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.15",
    "next": "^14.1.0",
    "postcss": "8.4.28",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.20",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.23.0",
    "@jest/globals": "^29.7.0",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^9.3.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.48",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.18",
    "@types/testing-library__jest-dom": "^6.0.0",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "encoding": "^0.1.13",
    "eslint": "^8.50.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-material-ui": "^1.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciate, thanks!

EDIT:

I am also seeing this in the browser console:

```
react-refresh-runtime.development.js:531 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at eval (react-refresh-runtime.development.js:531:9)
    at eval (react-refresh-runtime.development.js:543:7)
    at (:3000/app-pages-browser)/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-refresh/cjs/react-refresh-runtime.development.js (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/main-app.js?v=1706986671318:127:1)
    at options.factory (webpack.js?v=1706986671318:722:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?v=1706986671318:37:33)
    at fn (webpack.js?v=1706986671318:377:21)
    at eval (runtime.js:3:22)
    at (:3000/app-pages-browser)/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-refresh/runtime.js (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/main-app.js?v=1706986671318:138:1)
    at options.factory (webpack.js?v=1706986671318:722:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?v=1706986671318:37:33)
```

Comment: Im facing the exact same issue after upgrading from NextJS 13.5.6 to 14.1

Answer (score 0):

You no longer need to import react in your components, so remove anything like this:

`import React from 'react';`
or
`import 'react';`

You can leave any non-default import in such as:

`import { useEffect } from 'React';`

Comment: Please add details/reference for "You no longer need to import react in your components" rather than just a flat statement perhaps.  i.e. is this a change from some release, no longer as of what/when?, point in time, other parts of setup etc.  Assume reader is a neophyte react developer new to all of it perhaps.

Comment: I had already tried doing that, however that didn't seem to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Id suggest migrating to the app router and following these two guides in order.
[Upgrade guide next 13](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/upgrading/version-13)
[Upgrade guide next 14](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/version-14)

Nextjs 13 changed to the app router. This means that the path for the import alias '@' will be wrong in your tsconfig.json.

After you have migrated to the app router try changing the following and see if it is working.

Instead of your tsconfig.json:

```json
"paths": {
  "@/*": [
    "./src/*"
  ]
},
```

Try this:

```json
"paths": {
  "@/*": [
    "./app/*"
  ]
},
```

Comment: That didn't seem to fix the issue unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v14.1.1-canary.44

See https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/61791 for additional information.